# Filtering directly and indirectly connected things from list

Tags: list, filter, components, ocaml

if you have a function "test a b" which returns true if a and b are connected directly and if you have a given unordered list of things, what would be an elegant and fast solution to filter all connected things from given list?

Example:

```
let test a b = let diff = a - b in diff == 0 ;;

let lst = [4;1;7;3;8;9;2;0] ;;

filter_connected 2 lst ;;

-> [4;1;3;2;0]
```

Any hints?

---

Hmmm, I will try to refine my question...

1. there exists an unsorted list of things, pE. "let lst = [a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h];;" with type
   val a' list
2. there exists also a function which decide if two things are directly connectable or in other words, if the two things are direct neighbours:
   val test : a' -> a' -> bool
3. what I need is a function which has three arguments, the first one is a specific thing, the second one the unsorted list of things as suggested above, the last one is the test-function described above: 
   val filter_connected : a' -> a' list -> (a' -> a' -> bool) -> a' list

if a <-> b are direct neigbours and b <-> c are direct neighbours then [a;b;c] are connected.

The suggested "List.filter () lst" does not help here, because it only filters the directed neighbours.

In the example above with a <-> b and b <-> c as direct neighbours in case of test-function, and all others not, the "filter_connected" call will be:

"filter_connected b lst (test);;"

and would return:
[a;b;c]

Hope it will be more clean...

Comment: I am pretty sure you mean `diff = 0` where you have written `diff == 0`, if only because they do the same things in the current implementations. But then again, if `test` is an example of what you mean by "connected", why do you not pass it to `filter_connected` and more importantly, isn't that definition of connectedness just equality and how is it supposed to be used to get `[4;1;3;2;0]`?

Comment: paste your code, and please format it to obtain better answers (if there's any better answer than Pascal's)

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that you want to get the elements of the original list that are at distance less than 2 from 2.

```
        Objective Caml version 3.11.1

# let test x = abs (x - 2) <= 2 ;;
val test : int -> bool = <fun>
# List.filter test [4;1;7;3;8;9;2;0] ;;
- : int list = [4; 1; 3; 2; 0]
#
```

`List.filter` is a function from the standard library. `List.filter f l` produces the list of elements of `l` for which `f` answers `true`.

Getting the function that decides if each element should go in the results list is orthogonal to the problem of filtering the list once you have this function, so you should do that first.

If you wish to use for `f` a function that is the transitive closure of a relation that you have, you can use the library [ocamlgraph](http://ocamlgraph.lri.fr/) to obtain that transitive closure. Specifically, of [these functions](http://ocamlgraph.lri.fr/doc/Pack.Graph.html), use `add_vertex` for each puzzle piece, `add_edge` for each relation that you have, and then apply function `transitive_closure` to get a new graph `g` in which you can ask if there is an edge between two elements `e1` and `e2` with `mem_edge g e1 e2`. The partially applied function `mem_edge g e1` can be passed to `List.filter`.

Comment: +1: for mentioning ocamlgraph, love this lib, it took me a while to understand, though. :-)